# Two InnoDB table Join taking a Day!! I can't use the MYISAM because my table goes over the MaxData Length. How to solve this problem?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables(InnoDB) one with 15 million records and the other with 14 million records and I need to do a Left Join on these tables based on a 'title reference'. I'm currently using a Innodb table as I may need to add more data to the resulting table in future. The query has been going on since yesterday.

This 'Title_reference' is a varchar(20), its not a primary key but there are no duplicates in either tables.

I have been checking the table status and it's being updated approximately every two hours. So Does that mean the query is active?

I have the 15 million table as the first in the order while doing the join.

Where am I making a mistake? How to solve this problem?

Comment: What is your `innodb_buffer_pool` setting?  And how large are your indexes on disk?

Comment: The sizes of my indexes are 290 MB and 122 MB and the data length is 1.72 GB & 673 Mb and my buffer pool size is 16 MB(I'm not allowed by ubuntu to change it..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the fields you're joining on are not indexed - and your query written so that it correctly uses the index - that's going to take a long time for sure. Make sure they are indexed and your query uses them (using EXPLAIN ), and then you might want to do some tuning - another subject entirely - to your MySQL server's configuration to handle large tables effectively - bigger key buffer, for example, will be useful.

Comment: The fields are indexed in BTREE index but I'm not sure whether the query is using them. How can I make sure the query uses the indexes properly? I'm sorry if this is a basic question..I'm new to mySQL!

Comment: If you run your query, prepending "EXPLAIN", you'll get diagnostic info about how MySQL interprets the query.